# How to loop over tasks with each task having another loop

Tags: ansible, nested-loops

I would like to loop a few tasks on var_1 with a loop on var_2 in each task.

I am trying to use include_tasks here but not sure if there is a better way.

I may have missed the syntax or the whole logic is wrong.  I get this error:
ERROR! Invalid options for include_tasks: type_name, type_attr

Any suggestions on how to get the desired output?

```
vars:
 var_1:
  - name: bla1
    attributes:
     - a
     - b
  - name: bla2
    attributes:
     - c
     - d
 var_2:
  - type: typ1
    typ_attr:
     - aa
     - bb
  - type: typ2
    typ_attr:
     - cc
     - dd

   #main.yml

    tasks:
      - include_tasks: supporting.yml type_name={{item.0.type}} type_attr = {{item.1}}
        loop: "{{ var_2|subelements('typ_attr') }}"

#supporting.yml

    - debug:
        msg: "name = {{item.0.name}}; nameattr = {{item.1}}; type = {{type_name}}; typeattr = {{type_attr}}
      loop: "{{var_1|subelements('attributes')}}"
```

Desired output:

name = bla1; nameattr = a; type = typ1; typeattr = aa

name = bla1; nameattr = a; type = typ1; typeattr = bb

name = bla1; nameattr = a; type = typ2; typeattr = cc

name = bla1; nameattr = a; type = typ2; typeattr = dd

name = bla1; nameattr = b; type = typ1; typeattr = aa

name = bla1; nameattr = b; type = typ1; typeattr = bb

name = bla1; nameattr = b; type = typ2; typeattr = cc

name = bla1; nameattr = b; type = typ2; typeattr = dd

name = bla2; nameattr = c; type = typ1; typeattr = aa

name = bla2; nameattr = c; type = typ1; typeattr = bb

name = bla2; nameattr = c; type = typ2; typeattr = cc

name = bla2; nameattr = c; type = typ2; typeattr = dd

name = bla2; nameattr = d; type = typ1; typeattr = aa

name = bla2; nameattr = d; type = typ1; typeattr = bb

name = bla2; nameattr = d; type = typ2; typeattr = cc

name = bla2; nameattr = d; type = typ2; typeattr = dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to use different *loop_var* inside the loop of the included task. The task below does the job.

```
- include_tasks: supporting.yml
  loop: "{{ var_2|subelements('typ_attr') }}"

$ cat supporting.yml
- debug:
    msg: "name = {{ item1.0.name }};
          nameattr = {{ item1.1 }};
          type = {{ item.0.type }};
          typeattr = {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ var_1|subelements('attributes') }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item1
```

Comment: Perfect!  That worked like a charm... Thank you Vladimir :)